# How to put individual id on image preview before uploading multiple file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am showing preview before uploading multiple images using JQuery. Preview is working fine but the problem is I want to give unique id on each images.
This is what I have done so far,

```
$(function() {
var imagesPreview = function(input, placeToInsertImagePreview) {
        if (input.files) {
var filesAmount = input.files.length;
for (i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(event) {
    $($.parseHTML('<img style="width:50%;margin:10px;" id="'+i+'"><input name="taken_date[]" class="date-taken" required="true" id="date-format" style="width:50%;margin:10px 10px 50px 10px;" placeholder="Taken date and time">')).attr('src', event.target.result).appendTo(placeToInsertImagePreview);
};
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[i]);
}
}}

$('#gallery-photo-add').on('change', function() {
        $(".gallery").empty();
        imagesPreview(this, 'div.gallery');
    });

});
```

Here you will see I have added id on image tag inside `render.onload` function. But every time this id is putting the number of images I am taking as input. Suppose if I try to upload 5 images then this id is becoming 5 always. If I am trying to upload 4 image then it is putting 4 always.

Here is the html code

```
  <input name="patient_image[]" type="file" multiple="true" id="gallery-photo-add" accept="image/*" required="true" />
<div class="gallery">
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not declaring your loop variable (`i`) and so it is implicitly becoming a Global and it is not providing loop iteration scope so you have a closure around `i`.

Change the declaration to use `let` to declare the loop counter, which gives block level scope and each iteration will have its own scope to store the counter in.

```
 for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare `i` with `let`

```
for (let i = 0; i < filesAmount; i++) {
```